# Container startup failed: Using Testcontainers Localstack 1.15.0-rc2 with Maven/Spring Boot in Integration test on Bitbucket Pipelines

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, bitbucket-pipelines, testcontainers

Error running Testcontainers Localstack(https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testcontainers/localstack/1.15.0-rc2) in Spring Boot Integration test.

It runs fine locally but then fails on Bitbucket pipelines.

**Error:**

```
Container startup failed

org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerLaunchException: Container startup failed

Caused by: org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerFetchException: Can't get Docker image: RemoteDockerImage(imageName=localstack/localstack:latest, imagePullPolicy=DefaultPullPolicy())

Caused by: com.github.dockerjava.api.exception.DockerException: Status 403: {"message":"authorization denied by plugin pipelines: Invalid content length provided"}
```

**pipelines.yml excerpt**

```
definitions:
  services:
    docker:
      memory: 2048
    localstack:
      image: localstack/localstack:latest
      environment:
        SERVICES: S3
        LOCALSTACK_HOSTNAME: localhost
        HOSTNAME: localhost

  steps:
    - parallel: &buildStepMain
        - step:
            name: Test 
            caches:
              - maven
            script:
              - export TESTCONTAINERS_RYUK_DISABLED=true
              - ./build.sh test 
            services:
              - docker
```

I already tried the remediations suggested here:  https://www.testcontainers.org/supported_docker_environment/continuous_integration/bitbucket_pipelines/

**Test code:**

```
@Rule
public LocalStackContainer localstack = new LocalStackContainer(     DockerImageName.parse("localstack/localstack:latest")).withServices(S3);
```

Localstack was an opensource project by Atlassian originally, I would think they would have first-class support for it.